# Refocusing Tkinter image window

Tags: python, tkinter, win32gui

Script2 displays an image and and closes the image after spacebar is being pressed. Script2 works perfectly alone.

Unfortunately when I use script1 to launch script2, I have to click/refocus the image window before I'm able to close the image with spacebar.

I've tried using win32gui module to refocus generated image window with separate script (focus.py). If I run focus.py by myself when the image is being displayed, I'm able to just press the spacebar and image window closes. However I've not been able to import focus.py script to script2.py succesfully (so that I would only have script1.py and script2.py.

```
script1:

action = raw_input("Pick a scenario: ")

if action == "1":
    execfile("script2.py")

else:
    print "Try again."
    return self
```

---

```
script2:

import os, sys
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def close_window(event):
    event.widget.quit()     

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind("<space>", close_window)

imagefile = "image1.png"

image1 = Image.open(imagefile)
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (image1.size[0],image1.size[1]))
tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
label_image = Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkpi)
label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=image1.size[0],height=image1.size[1])
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
focus.py

import win32gui

tk = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'tk')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(tk)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the tkinter [focus_set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method) and/or [focus_force](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_force-method) methods? Though, this may be a platform specific thing: windows may be preventing a child window from stealing focus for security reasons.